# Generate a single form field with ActiveField without using the template in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, active-form

I'm using the `Yii2` PHP framework and utilising [ActiveField](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html) (Bootstrap Version) to generate form fields, this makes use of the [$template](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#$template-detail) property which includes the wrapping tags and such.

I'm wondering if it's possible to generate a single field in the form *without* using the template whilst all other fields *do*.

I ask because I want it to generate a hidden field, which I am currently doing such as:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'some_id')->hiddenInput(['value' => $some_id])->label(false); ?>
```

This works fine, *however* because it wraps it inside the standard field html, the `margin-bottom` I have set on the class `.form-group` is added to this too and is causing an unwanted margin.

I know I can manually insert this field myself but then it won't get the correct form name for the field, such as `MyForm[some_id]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based off of information provided by Kiran Muralee's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39809908/472501) I did a little more investigation and found you can remove the wrapper elements *entirely* and just output the actual `input` field, which is what I wanted.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'some_id', ['template' => '{input}',
'options' => ['tag' => false]])->hiddenInput(['value' => $some_id])->label(false); ?>
```

Note the addition of the `'tag' => false` portion inside the `options` *array*.

**Note:** You must be using Yii `>=` `2.0.8` for this to work correctly as there was a bug prior to that, stated as:

> **Enh #10764**: yii\helpers\Html::tag() and ::beginTag() return content without any HTML when the $tag attribute is false or null (pana1990)

Comment: Yup good info and if you give tag as 'span' then field will get surrounded with span tag

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'some_id',
            ['template' => '{input}{error}',
             'options' => ['class' => 'your-class']]) ->
            hiddenInput(["value" => $someVal,
                         "class" => "your-class"
                ]) ?>
```

The options property specifies the The HTML attributes (name-value pairs) for the field container tag.I think this would solve your problem as `margin-bottom` value put on the class `form-group` doesn't affect anymore.

Comment: Yeah I know, but the caveat is this won't allow the ability to validate the field.

Comment: @Brett Ok I have now made an edit to the answer by doing some research.Check if this is what you require.I prevented the adding of class .form-group in input as well as surrounding div.

Comment: I just found a way to remove the wrapping tag completely; I will post an answer.